# Apache Ignite Web Console

Tags: ignite

I am inside a corporate firewall that does not allow me to access the free deployed instance at  https://console.gridgain.com/. I downloaded the source and tried to build but again the firewall does not allow me to go outside the network to retrieve the dependencies specified in the pom.xml file.
What are my options

Answer (score 1):

You can download binary build of Ignite Web Console from Apache Ignite, deploy it on premise.

You can also deploy paid version of GridGain, deploy it on premise.

Comment: is the WebConsole a separate download? I downloaded the binary build 2.7.6 from the apache ignite downloads page.

Comment: Download GridGain version of Web Console. It’s free and goes with advanced dashboard for monitoring: https://www.gridgain.com/resources/download

Comment: https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/build-and-deploy I guess you will have to build it from source.

Answer (score 1):

You can download WebConsole from the GridGain website by the following link: https://www.gridgain.com/resources/download

You can install it in your environment and use without needing to access external resources.

Comment: As I said in my original post, the gridgain site is inaccessible from inside the corporate network

Comment: In any way, you need to get the distributable package somehow. Otherwise you'll have to build it from sources that will require you to get access to a bunch of other resources where dependencies are stored.